# compare entity framework models

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, compare

I want to compare two models in different projects, to figure out they are the same or not, in the number of tables, table-names, table-columns, the relation between tables(important) and etc.

doesn't matter one of them using data-annotation and one of them using fluent API, I want to know they create the same database or not.

what is the best way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: ((IObjectContextAdapter)instance).ObjectContext contains the modelInformation (after the call to OnModelCreating()), so there's your best bet. a colleague of mine found the complete code to compare the models online.

Comment: You could schema compare the databases created in Visual Studio. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)